# GeoViewInputEventArgs e.Location is acting like null but I can see that it isn't null by drilling into it in the Watch

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, esri, .net-standard-2.0

I have a odd and frustrating issue.  I have a event that is doing this:

```
        private async void EsriMap_GeoViewTapped(object sender, GeoViewInputEventArgs e)
    {
            if(e.Location == null)
            {
               // The code always goes into this if statement
               // it is acting like a null
                bool b = true;
            }
    }
```

My xaml looks code looks like this:

```
        <esri:MapView x:Name="SiteMapView"
      Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
      Map="{ Binding Map }"
      GeoViewTapped="EsriMap_GeoViewTapped"
      GraphicsOverlays="{Binding GraphicsOverlays}" />
```

But if I look in the watch and type 'e' and then drill into it and then drill into Location I see the properties that I am expecting.

If I type 'e.Location' in the watch the output of the watch is blank (doesn't say null).  Also when I do this I noticed that in the output window I get this repeated exception text that is repeated like 10 times:

> System.ArgumentException: The field 'k__BackingField' is not
>   valid for this type.    at
>   Mono.Debugger.Soft.ObjectMirror.GetValues(IList`1 fields) in
>   E:\A\_work\785\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Mono.Debugger.Soft\ObjectMirror.cs:line
>   93    at Mono.Debugger.Soft.ObjectMirror.GetValue(FieldInfoMirror
>   field) in
>   E:\A\_work\785\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugger.Soft\Mono.Debugger.Soft\ObjectMirror.cs:line
>   74    at Mono.Debugging.Soft.FieldValueReference.get_Value() in
>   E:\A\_work\785\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging.Soft\FieldValueReference.cs:line
>   129    at Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ValueReference.GetChild(String
>   name, EvaluationOptions options) in
>   E:\A\_work\785\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ValueReference.cs:line
>   274    at
>   Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.NRefactoryExpressionEvaluatorVisitor.VisitMemberReferenceExpression(MemberReferenceExpression
>   memberReferenceExpression) in
>   E:\A\_work\785\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\NRefactoryExpressionEvaluatorVisitor.cs:line
>   1042    at
>   ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.MemberReferenceExpression.AcceptVisitor[T](IAstVisitor`1
>   visitor) in
>   E:\A_work\785\s\external\NRefactory\ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp\Ast\Expressions\MemberReferenceExpression.cs:line
>   105    at
>   Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.NRefactoryExpressionEvaluator.Evaluate(EvaluationContext
>   ctx, String expression, Object expectedType) in
>   E:\A_work\785\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\NRefactoryExpressionEvaluator.cs:line
>   82    at
>   Mono.Debugging.Evaluation.ObjectValueAdaptor.GetExpressionValue(EvaluationContext
>   ctx, String exp) in
>   E:\A_work\785\s\external\debugger-libs\Mono.Debugging\Mono.Debugging.Evaluation\ObjectValueAdaptor.cs:line
>   1411

I also have used similar code in another project and I didn't have this weird thing happen.
Any ideas on what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After about two days of looking at this issue with another developer I found out that the ESRI library I was using has the class GeoViewInputEventArgs in two different namespaces.  The classes must be identical or very close to being identical.  So after switching to the right namespace it now works as expected.  I really don't know why anyone would use the same class name in their library.